# Finding the optimal binary matrix via integer programming in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

I tried implementing the solution in [optimal binary matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275440/finding-the-optimal-binary-matrix) using Matlab function `intlinprog` to a test input as in the following code

```
a=[450;400;250;200]; % test input
b=[750;500]; % test input
n = 4; % length of a
m = 2; % length of b
oness=ones(m,1);
f = (kron(a,oness))'; % objective function
cont1=kron(eye(n),oness'); 
cont2=-cont1;
cont3=-kron(a',eye(m));
A=[cont1;cont2;cont3];
bb=[ones(n,1);-zeros(n,1);-b];
lb = zeros(m*n,1);
ub = [ones(m*n,1)]; % enforces binary
intcon= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]; % all variable should be integers  
 Aeq = [];
 beq = [];
x = intlinprog(f,intcon,A,bb,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
```

However, I am getting the message

> `Intlinprog` stopped because no integer points satisfy the constraints.

An obvious optimal solution for this test input would be `x = [0;1;1;0;1;0;0;0]`.

However, if I remove the integrality constraints via `intcon=[]`, I get an optimal solution. Why can't the function find the minimum solution with integral constraints?

Comment: Try to generate the test inputs randomly. You may have picked test inputs for which the corresponding polytope does not contain any integer points.

Comment: I had a mistake in the problem definition that I have fixed now. The code now give output correctly. I am posting the new code as an answer. Many thanks to @RodrigodeAzevedo for your sincere support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a mistake in the problem definition that I have fixed now. The code now give output correctly. Below is the correct code:

```
a=[450;400;250;200]; % test input
b=[750;500]; % test input
n = 4;
m = 2;
oness=ones(m,1);
f = -(kron(a,oness))';
cont1=kron(eye(n),oness');
cont2=-cont1;
cont3=kron(a',eye(m));
A=[cont1;cont2;cont3];
bb=[ones(n,1);-zeros(n,1);b];
lb = zeros(m*n,1);
ub = [ones(m*n,1)]; % enforces binary
intcon= 1:8;
 Aeq = [];
 beq = [];
x = intlinprog(f,intcon,A,bb,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
```

Answer:

`x = [1;0;0;1;1;0;0;0]` which give same optimal result as

`x = [0;1;1;0;1;0;0;0]`